# phpmailer not working after migration to php 7

Tags: php, php-7.0

Below is my php code

Previously the server was on php 5.9 and we recently updated it to php 7.0

while sending mail we get below error it says SMTP error but the credentials are correct

Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
<?php
$cname = $_REQUEST[ 'cname' ];
//echo $cname;
$email = $_REQUEST[ 'email' ];
//echo $email.',';
$phone = $_REQUEST[ 'phone' ];
//echo $phone.',';
$datetime = $_REQUEST[ 'datetime' ];
//echo $datetime.',';
$package = $_REQUEST[ 'packages' ];
//echo $package.',';


$message = '<table style="height: 231px; width: 490px; float: left;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 21.5px;">
<td style="width: 235.433px; height: 21.5px;"><strong>Name:-</strong></td>
<td style="width: 253.567px; height: 21.5px;">' . $cname . '</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 235.433px; height: 21px;"><strong>Email:-</strong></td>
<td style="width: 253.567px; height: 21px;">' . $email . '</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 235.433px; height: 21px;"><strong>Phone No:-</strong></td>
<td style="width: 253.567px; height: 21px;">' . $phone . '</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 235.433px; height: 21px;"><strong>Date & Time:-</strong></td>
<td style="width: 253.567px; height: 21px;">' . $datetime . '</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21.5px;">
<td style="width: 235.433px; height: 21.5px;"><strong>Packages:-</strong></td>
<td style="width: 253.567px; height: 21.5px;">' . $package . '</td>
</tr>';

require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
// require_once "PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

// Instantiate Class  
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Set up SMTP  
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Sets up a SMTP connection  
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;       // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; //"ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection 
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

//$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
$mail->Host = "mail.test.com";
$mail->Port = '465'; //'465';  //Gmail SMTP port
$mail->Encoding = '8bit';

// Authentication  

$mail->Username = "testuser@test.com";
$mail->Password = "password";


// Compose
$mail->SetFrom( 'testuser@test.com', 'Test' );

$mail->Subject = "Appointment for $package has been received"; // Subject (which isn't required)  
$mail->MsgHTML( $message );

// Send To  
//$mail->AddAddress("", "Recipient Name"); // Where to send it - Recipient
//$mail->AddAddress("testuser@test.com", "Recipient Name");



// $result = $mail->Send();     // Send!  
//$message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!'; 
//$message = $result ? header("Location:thank_you.php"); : 'Sending Failed!';      
//unset($mail);

if ( !$mail->send() ) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo '<br>Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
    .text-xs-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}
.jumbotron {
    padding: 4rem 2rem;
}
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #eceeef;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    padding: 5rem 1rem;
}
        .display-3 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    font-family: Poiret One; font-weight: bold;
}
        .lead {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: Poiret One; font-weight: bold;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: Poiret One; font-weight: bold;
}
    .thankyou-check {
    color: #15639a;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 6px;    
}
    </style>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo  file_get_contents('header.php'); ?>
    <div class="jumbotron text-xs-center">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle thankyou-check"></i>
  <h1 class="display-3">Thank You!</h1>
  <p class="lead">for your appointment and We will get back to you soon.</p>
</div>  
    <?php echo  file_get_contents('footer.php'); ?>
</body>

    enter code here

</html>
```

Comment: Enable SMTP debug: $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; and check what it says

Comment: Try using port `587` as `465` is port for gmail and you have update host.

Comment: SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.8 @klian

Comment: @LovepreetSingh changing port didn't help

Comment: Error 535 is a authentication problem. You will have to check that credentials are correct: SMTP host is correct. Username is correct. Password is correct. Port is correct. Authentication method is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change line number 459 and replace `split` function by `explode` function.

```
-  $toArr = split(',', $to);
+  $toArr = explode(',', $to);
```

Comment: That's not related to the problem at all. The problem of OP is authentication issue.